# Rewriting integral (normal distribution)

Tags: integration, solution-verification, proof-explanation, normal-distribution

I have the following integral $$\int_0^a \phi(\frac{z-s}{\sigma})ds$$ with $z>a$, and I think I can rewrite it as
$$\int_z^{z+a} \phi(\frac{s-a}{\sigma})ds$$

However, I would like to verify my intuition but can't really derive the second expression from the first one and I guess I am missing one obvious step.

I can only see that
$$\int_z^{z+a} \phi(\frac{s-a}{\sigma})ds=\int_0^{a} \phi(\frac{z+s-a}{\sigma})ds$$

Therefore, I would only need to show that $$\int_0^{a} \phi(\frac{z+s-a}{\sigma})ds=\int_0^a \phi(\frac{z-s}{\sigma})ds$$
Which should hold since both functions' values are integrated in the reverse order. Nonetheless, I have no idea how I could prove that both are equivalent. Could anyone help me on this?

Thank you very much in advance! :-)